# NPE creating system fonts?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying out CodenameOne and I get an NPE which seems to have something to do with the System Fonts.  This is in the Simulator on macOS.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.Font.<init>(Font.java:99)
at com.codename1.ui.Font.createSystemFont(Font.java:345)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.resetThemeProps(UIManager.java:402)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.<init>(UIManager.java:107)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getInstance(UIManager.java:125)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.getUIManager(Component.java:898)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.<init>(Component.java:687)
at com.driveweb.savvyPanel.TilePanel.<init>(TilePanel.java:22)
```

I expect this is a rookie mistake - maybe something in the configuration.  Any ideas?  thx.

Comment: The Codename One implementation isn't loading so it's null. How are you running the project and what did you change about that?

Comment: From a menu:  Run -> Run 'Run in Device Simulator'.  I don't remember chaging anything, but I guess I probably did.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Did you customize the run path or project paths in some ways? Which JVM are you using?

Comment: Your comments led me to the solution: I was creating my object via a static declaration, which I guess doesn't work for CodenameOne?  I moved the constructor inside a method called from the app inti() and the NPE does not occur.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use pure java code in static initialized variables. You can't reference GUI, storage or similar Codename One features. The library isn't initialized before the `init(Object)` method is invoked and a static initializer can happen before that.